# Graph API query for a Teams Channel by DisplayName returns no results

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We are trying to query for the ID of a Teams channel based on its name.

Step one is `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams?$select=id,displayName&$filter=DisplayName%20eq%20'{name}'`. This works just fine and returns the expected Team ID.

Step two is `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamId}/channels?$select=id,displayName&$filter=DisplayName%20eq%20'{name}'`.

Up until about 2 weeks ago, this query also worked as expected. Now, we get no results. Not an error, not a 404, just an empty result set. This is happening with both the .NET and JavaScript SDK. The channels have existed for a long time and have not been changed recently. I am using a token with app-level permissions for Group.ReadWrite.All and Team.ReadBasic.All.

Comment: in case anyone is looking for this endpoint now (Jan 2023), it is not in v1.0 of the API, but is in the beta version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your query or with permissions. It's bug in Graph API for channels when `$select` is added.

[Issue 1](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/11472)

[Issue 2](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/11494)